# How to Acess Remote Computer Folders in PS SQLSERVER:\>

Tags: sql-server, powershell, remote-access

Recently I came to know how to use Powersehll commands for executing SQL queries as mentioned below:

```
Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking   

$ds=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -Database $Database -ServerInstance $server -ConnectionTimeout $ConnectionTimeout -QueryTimeout $QueryTimeout
```

At this time Powershell ISE output Console will be in

```
PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

I was able to perform Select and Update queries without any error. The problem is faced when I wanted to access one of the file in remote computer. I tried to access the file as below:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> Get-Content -Path \\Server\D$\Log\App.log
```

Even tried, just to list files/folders as

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> ls \\Server\D$\Log\
```

Iam getting below errors:

Get-Content : Cannot find path '\Server\D$\Log\App.log' because it does not exist.
   ls : Cannot find path '\Server\D$\Log\' because it does not exist.

Need not to say- folder and file exists on that server as I was able to access the same when Powershell is running without SQL module. I mean console was showing just 
     PS C:\User\abc\

Sorry for this long story-- now, simple question!
How to access remote files/folders when Shell is in SQLSERVER console?

Thanks in Advance!

-Raj

Comment: You should ensure that the account used to connect has proper access to the UNC path you're accessing. I'm guessing it might be trying to connect under the credentials of the SQL Server.

Comment: I am using my Administrator Account which has access to both SQL server and remote Server (where file is located)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the filesystem provider explicitly like this:

```
ls filesystem::\\server\d$\log
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you too.. tip from **steoleary** and you- both are simple and works perfectly. It helped me a lot..

Thanks again! Happy Scripting..

Answer (score 0):

Just change your directory like so:

```
cd c:\
```

then:

```
ls \\server\d$\log
```

you can then change back to sql server by doing the same:

```
cd sqlserver:\
```

The powershell providers can be used just like you would a normal drive letter, pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's running the commands remotely on the SQL server, which makes accessing data on another server from there  a "double hop" scenario, and you'll need CredSSP auth for that to work.....

Comment: It's not that, because the command prompt shows as SQLSERVER:\ he is using a different provider, not the filesystem provider, therefore trying to access the filesystem that way won't work, you can navigate around SQL server objects using that provider, not the file system until you change back.